# Running subprocess.Popen as administrator

Tags: python, windows, cmd, uac, administrator

```
# This is a method executed by a remote host

actual_cmd = 'cmd /c echo hi > output.txt'

cmd = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(actual_cmd), shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
s.send(output_bytes)
```

Current Output: "Access Denied"

**Since UAC doesn't give Admin rights even as the Administrator USER, I want to find a way to run the command as administrator (I am an administrator).**

Comment: `Popen` calls `CreateProcess`, which by design cannot elevate to an administrator's unrestricted token. You can use the task scheduler. You have to get administrator access once in order to create a task that runs with highest privileges. From then on you can run the task by name via `schtasks /run /tn task_name`.

Comment: Side note: using `shell=False` with a shell command is odd, and using a list in this case is unsupported since `subprocess.list2cmdline` doesn't know how to quote and escape a command line for cmd.exe. You could simply use `Popen(actual_cmd, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`. And you should definitely use `cmd.communicate()` when reading from both stdout and stderr. It avoids deadlocks.